# Conditional Format to highlight past and future dates

Tags: excel, format, conditional-statements

I have a spreadsheet that has 5 columns of dates the all refer to one key date.

The key date is the date of sign off for a piece of work, the other columns reference that date, and subtract 2, 6, 8, 10 and 14 days to show the dates that each stage needs to be completed by.

The conditional format I want to be able to create needs to take the day (TODAY()) then look across all dates and apply the following format:

If dates in the range are this week, then highlight the cells green
If dates in the range are last week, then highlight the cells amber
If dates in the range are greater than last week, then highlight the cells red
If dates in the range are greater than next week, then highlight the cells light green

Every option I've tried the range only gets one of the formats applied.

The purpose is to allow my team to see at a glance actions that need to be closed because they are either out of date, or just about to be.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Andrew.

Comment: You need to use a formula-based rule for each condition.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add three conditional format rules to make this happen and each will need to be based on a formula.

Formula to identify dates older than 2 weeks:

```
=DATEDIF(C12,TODAY(),"d")>14
```

Formula to identify dates last week:

```
=AND(DATEDIF(C12,TODAY(),"d")<=14,DATEDIF(C12,TODAY(),"d")>7)
```

Formula to identify dates this week:

```
=AND(DATEDIF(C12,TODAY(),"d")<=7,DATEDIF(C12,TODAY(),"d")>0)
```

[image]